# Getting infinite loop with useEffect with dependency, without dependency app doesn't work

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, axios, request, dependencies

```
useEffect(() => {
    const fetchData = async () => {
      try {
        const response = await axios.get('http://localhost:8888/todos');
        console.log('Response:', response.data);
        const todosWithBooleanDone = response.data.map(todo => ({
          id: todo.id,
          name: todo.name,
          done: todo.done === 1,
        }));
        console.log('Setting todos:', todosWithBooleanDone);
        setTodos(todosWithBooleanDone);
      } catch (error) {
        console.error('Error fetching todos:', error);
      }
    };

    fetchData();
  }, [todos]);
```

I don't expect millions of requests.
Without the dependency todos in the array, my app doesn't work!
I thought to add a new useEffect but it doesn't work the same.
I am close to the solution but I really don't know how to fix it.

Answer (score 0):

Your `useEffect` is being called every time there is an update on `todos` and there you are repeatedly calling `setTodos` to update `todos` which leads to infinite calls.

Your first `useEffect` can be without a dependency to be run only on component mount to fetch and set `todos`.

```
useEffect(() => {
    const fetchData = async () => {
      try {
        const response = await axios.get('http://localhost:8888/todos');
        console.log('Response:', response.data);
        const todosWithBooleanDone = response.data.map(todo => ({
          id: todo.id,
          name: todo.name,
          done: todo.done === 1,
        }));
        console.log('Setting todos:', todosWithBooleanDone);
        setTodos(todosWithBooleanDone);
      } catch (error) {
        console.error('Error fetching todos:', error);
      }
    };

    fetchData();
  }, []); // <-- Without dependency
```

Another `useEffect` to run every time todos changes.

```
useEffect(() => {
    // Your code whenever todos changes.
}, [todos]); // <--- With dependency
```

Comment: It's not functioning, and I've tried addressing it by incorporating a second useEffect; however, regrettably, I haven't discovered any resolutions.